# PackedArray version of Chop

Tags: performance-tuning, packed-arrays

I'm a big fan of [`Chop`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Chop.html). It's fast and useful in pre-rounding transforms and things

Unfortunately it also necessarily unpacks a real `PackedArray` (it's rounding approximate `0` to true integer `0`). It does that even when it doesn't actually have to:

```
bigList =
  BlockRandom[SeedRandom[1]; RandomReal[{}, {1000, 1000}]];

Developer`PackedArrayQ@bigList

True

Chop[bigList] === bigList

True

Chop[bigList] // Developer`PackedArrayQ

False
```

And, of course, it unpacks when it has to:

```
Chop[bigList, 10^-5] == bigList

False

Chop[bigList, 10^-5] // Developer`PackedArrayQ

False
```

Is there any built-in packed `Chop`?

I could of course implement an array chop like:

```
packChop =
 Compile[
  {
   {arr, _Real, 2},
   {tol, _Real}
   },
  Map[
   If[Abs[#] < tol, 0., #] &,
   arr,
   {2}
   ],
  RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
  ]

packChop[bigList, 10^-$MachinePrecision] // Developer`PackedArrayQ

True

packChop[bigList, 10^-$MachinePrecision] // RepeatedTiming // First

0.071
```

Or just do it in top-level code:

```
chop[a_, t_] :=
 With[{r = N@t},
  Map[
   If[Abs[#] < r, 0., #] &,
   bigList,
   {2}
   ]
  ]

chop[bigList, 10^-$MachinePrecision] // Developer`PackedArrayQ

True

chop[bigList, 10^-$MachinePrecision] // RepeatedTiming // First

0.085
```

But it's always nice to use the built-ins (even if unpacking makes them slow):

```
uBigList = bigList;
uBigList[[1, 1]] = 1;

Chop@bigList // RepeatedTiming // First

0.089

Chop@uBigList // RepeatedTiming // First

0.033
```

Comment: I guess you are looking for `Threshold`...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher that is exactly what I’m looking for. Let’s see if there’s a duplicate we can resolve this to (feels like there should be although I didn’t see it earlier).